Read-only excel form with button to pop to outlook. How to track actual outlook send out time in separate excel/wherever as a report?
I have created a excel VBA form.
After click the button, it will bring all TO, CC, Subject, Body to Outlook and display to user.
If user is ok with it, they will send out the email at outlook.
This is a read-only form with protected workbook password.
So, if I want to track the actual count of how many email send out with username, timestamp, button name.
Any suggestion?
My ideal result is to have an excel report on these details? Is it feasible?
I have check some threads on using "CMailItemEvents" but I can't come up with an solution, not to say the code.
Thanks a lot for your help!!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
